# Laravel 4; OneToMany- Call to a member function count() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel-4, one-to-many

I have the following controllers:

```
class ProjectsController extends \BaseController {
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Task');
    }
}

class TasksController extends \BaseController {
    public function project() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Project');
    }
}
```

If I call `$project->tasks->count()` in my view, I get an error **Call to a member function count() on a non-object**

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.flynsarmy.com/2013/12/creating-a-basic-todo-application-with-laravel-4-part-2/) on creating a todo list, and everything went well up until this point.  I really hope someone can assist.

Comment: You seem to be confusing Models with Controllers.

Comment: I gathered as much.  Thanx, Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And then I ask myself.... why would you put that function in the Controller instead of the Model?

So, I moved the functions from the controllers to the models and all is well.

Sometimes it helps to switch one's brain on :) lol